# Error on os.walk – I need the result for the specified directory only

Tags: python

Here is a demo what works for me and what doesn't:

```
import os
path2   = 'D:\\'

# this works
for curdir, dirlist, flist in os.walk(path2):
    pass

# this fails
curdir, dirlist, flist = os.walk(path2)
```

Comment: and why do you believe the one that fails should work?

Comment: `os.walk` yields zero or more 3-tuples. The assignment will fail with either too few values to unpack or too many values to unpack. Except in the case when it yields exactly 3 times. Even in that case the results won't be what you expect them to be.

Answer (score 2):

The thing is that [`os.walk()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk) returns a generator. So doing:

```
curdir, dirlist, flist = os.walk(path2)
```

Might or might not work.

First let's consider this:

```
for curdir, dirlist, flist in os.walk(path2):
    pass
```

This is essentially the same as assigning the generator returned by [`os.walk()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk) to a name and continuously calling [`next()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) on that until a `StopIteration` is raised.

```
walk = os.walk(path2)

try:
    while True:
        dirpath, dirnames, filenames = next(walk)

        ... do something ...
except StopIteration:
    pass
```

Now if we go back to the other example:

```
curdir, dirlist, flist = os.walk(path2)
```

Then the above is the same as doing:

```
walk = os.walk(path2)
curdir = next(walk)
dirlist = next(walk)
flist = next(walk)
```

If the generator yields 3 or more values then that won't fail. If it however yields less than 3 values then it will fail, since there's less than 3 values to unpack.

So if the generator returned by [`os.walk()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk) only yields a single value.

```
curdir, dirlist, flist = os.walk(path2)
```

Then the above will result in the following error:

> ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 1)

If it's because you only need the first value, then go ahead and directly call [`next()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next). However be sure to catch any potential `StopIteration`.

```
try:
    curdir, dirlist, flist = next(os.walk(path2))
except StopIteration:
    pass
```

Lastly. Unless it's because you're utilizing `dirlist` and `flist` as an easy way to get the directories and files at a given path. Then you might not need [`os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk) and can instead just use [`os.listdir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir) or [`os.scandir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.scandir).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly what you want is not `os.walk` which outputs the list of files/directories in every subdirectory of `path2` but [`os.scandir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.scandir) which lists all entries inside `path2` itself.

Example from the docs linked above:

```
with os.scandir(path) as it:
    for entry in it:
        if not entry.name.startswith('.') and entry.is_file():
            print(entry.name)
```